# Having an issue with a loop in Java. Explanation in description

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, char

I am creating a program that counts the number of vowels, consonants, spaces, and punctuation in a string. Before moving on to anything else, I'm making sure that the vowel checker works. I've created a loop that seems to work logically, as I've run it through a java visualizer, and everything checks out. But, I get an error when I run it through the BlueJ IDE. It says: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range. I have no idea what the issue is, and I would appreciate any and all help. This is a link to the [java visualizer](https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize/#mode=display) if anyone wants to test it for themselves, and I have the code posted below:

```
//**************************************************************
 // Testing program for VCP program (temporary).
 //
 // @aaron_ford
 // @version_1.0_11.9.17
 //**************************************************************
public class VCPTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a string.");
        String user_str = "a vowel is here";
        System.out.println("You entered: " + user_str);

        char vowels[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};

        // counter variables
        int v_counter = 0;
        int c_counter = 0;
        int s_counter = 0;
        int p_counter = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int str_compare = user_str.charAt(count);

        for (; count < str_compare; count++)
        {
            str_compare = user_str.charAt(count);
            for (int a:vowels)
            {
                if (a == str_compare)
                {
                    v_counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("There are " + v_counter + " vowels.");
        System.out.println("There are " + c_counter + " consonants.");
        System.out.println("There are " + s_counter + " spaces.");
        System.out.println("There are " + p_counter + " punctuation marks.");
    }     
}
```

Comment: What's the logic of checking `count < str_compare` when `str_compare = user_str.charAt(count)`??

Comment: Shouldn't your for loop condition be `count < user_str.length()`?

Comment: Try this: `for (char c : user_str.toCharArray()) for (char v : vowels) if (c == v) v_counter++;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your "for" loop. You check if count value is less than str_compare value (which is a numeric representation of character from given string). I think this is not what you were expecting. I would suggest few little modifications - it provides checking character from given string ( `str_compare = user_str.charAt(count);` ) and after every loop `count` value is being increased to check next character from this string. In every loop there is validation made, to check whether the end of string is currently reached (`count < user_str.length()`)

```
for (count = 0; count < user_str.length(); count++)
        {
            str_compare = user_str.charAt(count);
            for (int a : vowels)
            {
                if (a == str_compare)
                {
                    v_counter++;
                }
            }
        }
```

And now the output of your program looks better:

```
Enter a string.
You entered: a vowel is here
There are 6 vowels.
There are 0 consonants.
There are 0 spaces.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the problem that I had.

Comment: That's great it helped you, wish you all the best!